# Woodstox parser doesn't support certain unicode character

Tags: java, xml

I am new at using WoodStox. I have to read all possible combination of Unicode character and write to XML file. WoodStox fails wile reading certain Unicode character. Can some one help me how can i either skip the character when encountered or some solution to write that Unicode character in XML file.

The exception i get is 
    Error on line 1 column 1404735 of 24364002-data-set-results.xml:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Character reference "&#xfffe" is an invalid XML   character.
Exception is : net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#xfffe" is an invalid XML character.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with WoodStox either, but I can say that FFFE is indeed not a valid Unicode character, so it is probably more a problem with the input than with the parser. FFFE is most commonly used by some encoders in UTF-16 encoding to indicate the byte order (little or big endian). Depending on whether it is read back as FFFE or as FEFF, the decoder knows which byte order to choose. But it is not a standard and not all decoders support it.

When used as such, it is always the first two bytes of the file.

So, what you need to check is:

- Are you using the correct character encoding (usually either UTF-8 or UTF-16)?
- If using UTF-16, does your file start with FFFE or FFEF?
- Does WoodStox have a setting that enables automatically detection of byte order?

Worst case, if your file starts with FFFE or FFEF, simply remove it from the file before you feed it to WoodStox. Make sure that you set the correct byte-order in WoodStox, though.

Comment: Woodstox does automatically handle BOMs, by default, so it should be handled correctly as long as input comes as byte stream (`InputStream`). The only way to sneak in one is to either have double BOM, or manually construct a `Reader` that decodes BOM into character -- once there's `char` with that value, it won't be BOM.